# Question about rational functions of the 'variables' in an arbitrary set $X$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, field-theory, axiom-of-choice

I was reading the [proof](https://dept.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Eablass/bases-AC.pdf) given by Blass that the *Existence of bases implies the axiom of choice*. At the beginning of the proof he presents in that paper, the following is written:

> Adjoin all the elements of $X=\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i$ as indeterminates to some (arbitrary) field $k$, obtaining the field $k(X)$ of rational functions of the "variables" in $X$. For each $i\in I$, we define the $i$-degree of a monomial to be the sum of the exponents of members of $X_i$ in that monomial.

Here $\{X_i\mid i\in I\}$ is a family of non empty sets that is pairwise disjoint.

**My question is:** If $X$ is an arbitrary set, with no clear algebraic structure defined, how can we speak of *exponents* of elements of $X$?

---

I am aware that we can form the ring $k(X)$ of polynomials in $X$ whenever $X$ has some operation defined, since exponentiation can be seen as a repeated application of the operation to the same element in this case. But I'm struggling to make sense of the definition in general. What would $x^n$ mean if $x\in X$ was... a set itself?

This is something that I have encountered previously when I saw linear combinations of simplices in algebraic topology. But every time I come across this concept I get more confused. My attempt to understand this was to consider each polynomial as a finite sequence, with the coefficients of the polynomial being the terms of the sequence, but what if the index set $I$ was uncountable? and what would it mean to multiply two variables $x_ix_j$ in $X$?

Also, is the concept of "free groups" related to this? In [this article](https://www.math.unl.edu/%7Embrittenham2/classwk/990s08/public/myasnikov.1.free.groups.pdf), the *group word* looks similar to raising elements of $X$ to some power.

Any help is gladly appreciated.

Comment: Axiomatically, the polynomial ring over $k$ in $X=\{X_i\}$ is the $k$-module $$\bigoplus_{\oplus_X \mathbb{N}}k$$ with suitable multiplication structure. The element that has 1 in $s=(s_i), s_i=\nu_i$ if $i\in J, J=\{j_1,\dots, j_n\}$ finite,$s_i=0$ else and has 0 else is denoted by $X_{j_1}^{\nu_{j_1}}\dots X_{j_n}^{\nu_{j_n}}.$ Its field of fractions is called the rational functions over $k$ in $X$.

Comment: The sentence "a family of non empty sets that is pairwise disjoint" is cryptic. They mean that $\{X_i,i\in I\}$ is a collection of variables, similar to the polynomial ring in $n$ variables but instead of $1\ldots n$ the set of variables is indexed by an arbitrary large set $I$. So $X_iX_j$ works the same way as $xy$ in $K[x,y]$, product of two distinct variables. $K(\{ X_i,i\in I\})$ is the union of all the $K(X_{i_1},\ldots,X_{i_m})$ with the obvious inclusions.